# Is there a known issue where Fullcalendar renders in Chinese on Safari (despite language settings?)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, safari, fullcalendar

I've been trying to render a calendar using Fullcalendar as a partial in my Rails 4 App.

It only renders in Chinese  (despite setting the language to English both in the js file and the live script). Also, it's just the Letters that are in hanzi, the numbers are roman numerals.

In Chrome and Firefox, the calendar works fine and renders in English.  I have never set any defaults to Chinese on any of my browsers, so I really don't understand.

I have even created a fully new app with none of my other css or js so that I could be sure their were no weird conflicts.  Literally all that's running on this app is the fullcalendar.js, jquery, jquery_ujs, gcal, fullcalendar.css, moment.css & turbolinks.

Below are the two calls of Javascript I've used and they BOTH return only Chinese letters (but Roman numerals).

```
<script> $(document).ready(function() {

// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: '/events.json',
        lang: 'en',


})
```

});

```
<script>
```

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
/* initialize the external events
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

jQuery('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

  // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
  // it doesn't need to have a start or end
  var eventObject = {
    title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
  };
  
  // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
  jQuery(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
  
  // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
  jQuery(this).draggable({
    zIndex: 999,
    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
    revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
  });
  
});


/* initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',

    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },

  editable: true,
  droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
  drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped
  
    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
    var originalEventObject = jQuery(this).data('eventObject');
    
    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
    
    // assign it the date that was reported
    copiedEventObject.start = date;
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
    
    // render the event on the calendar
    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
    
    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
    if (jQuery('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
      // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
      jQuery(this).remove();
    }
    
  }
});
```

});

I've been trying to figure this out for days. and I'd LOVE some help.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.  So obvious.  I restarted Safari and it's fine.  I am worried that this will happen client side and so I'm hoping it's just a Localhost issue.